# Prove that for $n \geqslant 1,$ the integer $n(n+1)(2 n+1)$ is divisible by 6

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that for $n \geqslant 1,$ the integer $n(n+1)(2 n+1)$ is divisible by $6.$

My attempt. We enough to show that $2|n(n+1)(2 n+1)$ and $3|n(n+1)(2 n+1)$. Note that any integer $n$ is of the form: $2k$ or $2k+1.$

So $n(n+1)(2n+1)=2k(2k+2)(4k+1)$. Hence $2|2k(2k+2)$, that is $2|n(n+1)$.

**How can I continue this proof? Can you help?**

Comment: any integer is either $3m,3m+1,3m+2$. Then proceed as when You proved it is divisible by $2$.

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja Thanks for helping, I needed this too much  to complete proof :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say $95\%+$ of these sorts of statements can be done by induction. So when you don't have a clue, go with that as a starter. Maximilian's proof is very elegant, but if you can't spot the identity it's difficult to replicate

Firstly, verify the base case: $n=1$. Here we have $1\cdot 2\cdot 3=6$. Clearly this is divisible by $6$.

We then assume it true for $n=k$. That is: $$k(k+1)(2k+1)=6\lambda\tag 1$$
and use this to show it true for $k+1$, i.e. that $$(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)=6\mu\tag 2$$

Expanding $(1)$, we see $2k^3+3k^2+k=6\lambda$

and expanding $(2)$ gives $2k^3+9k^2+13k+6=6\mu$

Substitute in the $6\lambda$ into the expansion of $(2)$ and see what you get.

Comment: To be honest I don't think my proof should be taken too seriously but I just couldn't not post it 

Answer (score 7):

A cool proof is given by $$n(n+1)(2n+1)=6\cdot\sum_{k=1}^n k^2.$$

Comment: how can I use this?

Comment: Well $$6\cdot\sum_{k=1}^n k^2$$ is surely divisible by $6$ (and the formula can be proven straight-forwardly using induction)

Comment: @JamesEnsor $\sum k^2$ , which is the sum of 1st n  squares of natural numbers, so its definitely an integer, also $n(n+1)(2n+1)$ is clearly an integer

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch the proof is indeed "cool"

Comment: Thanks for comments and helping, the proof is very cool! :)

Comment: To be honest I don't think my proof should be taken too seriously but I just couldn't not post it 

Answer (score 1):

You can use the expansion of a polynomial using binomial coefficients, this is very useful for questions like *prove $P(n)$ is divisible by $k$*

$$n(n+1)(2n+1)=12\binom{n}{3}+18\binom{n}{2}+6\binom{n}{1}$$

Since binomial coefficients are integers, this is divisible by $6$.